# hibernate : select for update in two request

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my `springBoot` project, I'm using hibernate to acquire `lock` on my oracle database.

In my transaction, I execute the following code :

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM myTablem WHERE foo= :cat");
q.setParameter("cat", myValue);
q.setMaxResults(1);

//use pessimistic lock
//With Oracle, the select is a 'select for update' request
q.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

//set hibernate timeout to 0
//With Oracle, the 'select for update' is transformed in 'select for update nowait'
q.setHint("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 0);

List<Msisdn> msisdns = q.getResultList();
```

I want to execute a `"select for update"` on my database.
But with this code, hibernate executes two request :

> **Hibernate**: select * from ( select m..... from myTablem m cross join categorie_critere categoriec1_ where m.foo=... ) where rownum <= ?
>
> **Hibernate**: select ce_code_abpq from m where idpk1 =? and idpk2 =? and idpk3 =? for update nowait

In the first request, hibernate executes the `select` request. And in the second request, hibernates call a `"select for update"` on the selected element.

Is there a option to execute the `"select for update"` in only one request ?

Regards
Cédric

Answer (score 2):

To disable follow-on locking:

1. Upgrade to Hibernate 5.2.1
2. Either upgrade the database to 12c and use the `Oracle12cDialect`, or set the [`HINT_FOLLOW_ON_LOCKING`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/jpa/QueryHints.html#HINT_FOLLOW_ON_LOCKING) query hint to `false`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40115158/how-to-make-hibernate-lock-annotation-work-for-oracle-db) for more information.